# Not able to merge results from the three select statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

Hey look here i am trying to get result from these three select statements at once but i am noit able to do so. So please help me in rectifying my mistake. Don't rate me negative if you found my english or question method bad.

```
 $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT Count(c.c_id) from complaints c, users u,cell_num cn where c.status=? AND c.u_id_fk=u.u_id AND u.u_id=cn.u_id_fk");
 $sql->bind_param("i",$statOpen);

 $sql .= $conn->prepare("SELECT Count(c.c_id) from complaints c, users u,cell_num cn where c.status=? AND c.u_id_fk=u.u_id AND u.u_id=cn.u_id_fk");
 sql->bind_param("i",$statProgress);

 $sql .= $conn->prepare("SELECT Count(c.c_id) from complaints c, users u,cell_num cn where c.status=? AND c.u_id_fk=u.u_id AND u.u_id=cn.u_id_fk");
 $sql->bind_param("i",$statClosed);

                        $sql->execute();

                        $sql->store_result();

                        if($sql->num_rows > 0)
                        {
                            $sql->bind_result($c_id);

                            while( $sql->fetch() )
                            {
                                $user[] = array(
                               'c_id'=>$c_id


                             );
                            }
                            echo json_encode($user);


                            $sql->close();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(c.status = ?) cnt_open,
    sum(c.status = ?) cnt_progress,
    sum(c.status = ?) cnt_closed
from complaints c
inner join users u on u.u_id = c.u_id_fk
inner join cell_num cn on cn.u_id_fk = u.u_id
```

This query accepts three parameters at once, that correspond to the three values that you were passing to your three individual queries.

Note that I modified the query to use *standard* joins (with the `on` keyword) rather than old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause): this archaic syntax should not be used in new code.

You can make the query more efficient by adding a `where` clause that filters on the three possible `status`es (this requires passing each parameter twice):

```
where c.status in (?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: @M.A.Bell: yes; actually, `sum(c.status = ?)` is a MySQL shortcut for `sum(case when c.status = ? then 1 else 0 end)`.

Comment: I tried it on postgresql and it doesn't work, postgresql doesn't support this shortcut.

Comment: @M.A.Bell: indeed, this is MySQL-specific (which you tagged your question with). In Postgres, you can use the `sum(case ...)` solution, or use `count(*) filter(where c.status = ?)`

Comment: @GMB it's not my question, thank you for the information about postgresql

Comment: actually i had to count the c_id against different value of status , status has three values 0, 1, 2 . 
I want to output how many c_id have status 0, then how many c_id have status 1, and how many have status 2

Answer (score 0):

you can do so, it's more optimised

```
select c.statut,count(c.c_id)
from complaints c
inner join users u on u.u_id = c.u_id_fk
inner join cell_num cn on cn.u_id_fk = u.u_id
where c.status in (?, ?, ?)
group by c.status
```